# Reset Debian notebook without root priviliges

Tags: linux, debian

I have a notebook with Debian on it but I don't remember the root password anymore.

I tried resetting the notebook. If I try to open the advanced options for Debian in GRUB I need to enter my credentials and then it takes me back to the GRUB menu. I assume I also need the root credentials to get into the advanced options.

These are my options in the GRUB menu:

- Debian GNU/Linux
- Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux
- UEFI Firmware Settings

I can only enter Debian GNU/Linux with my non-root credentials.

Is there any other way I can make my notebook boot from a USB device? Is there maybe a factory reset button on some notebooks?

EDIT:
Turns out that my UEFI is password protected.

Comment: select "boot from USB" in your UEFI bootup phase? Typically, that's behind pressing some key (F2, F12, del…) right after powering on. What key you need depends on the individual notebook firmware.

Comment: I added a bit more detail to my description regarding the GRUB menu. I assume the boot from USB option should be among the other items? It isn't, in my case.

Comment: Grub has nothing to do with it. Once you're in GRUB, you're too far in the boot process.

Comment: Again, you usually just need to figure out which key when pressed right after power on takes you to a boot device selection, and then instead of selection the built-in SSD/HDD that contains your grub, you select an external USB stick.

Comment: Ah, F2 got me into the menu you described. However, the problem remains as I am asked for an admin password to unlock the Boot configuration.

Comment: Ah, so your UEFI is password protected, which would have nothing to do with your debian.

Comment: Yeah, I feel like my question completely misses the point now. Should I edit it or delete it alltogether?

Comment: I think it would be a nice idea to edit it significantly (add your notebook model, for example, as it is extremely relevant), and maybe move it to a different sister site – superuser.com would come to mind!

Comment: Can your non-root user use `sudo`?

Comment: If you don't have access to a different user on that system with sudo access, your last chance might be to take our the drive and attach it to a different machine with some adapter, and hope it's not encrypted.